# C# mp3 compression 64-bit

Tags: c#, windows, audio, 64-bit, mp3

The article at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5901/C-MP3-Compressor has a C# 32-bit implementation which wraps LAME's 32-bit mp3 audio encoder.  I've tried downloading that source code and converting it to 64 bit and using it with a more current LAME release [such as LAME 3.99.5 64bit from http://www.rarewares.org/mp3-lame-bundle.php], but I keep getting the error

> Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.

Any ideas on what would need to be done to that code to get it to work, or perhaps alternative open source C# solutions that already work for 64 bits?

Comment: Is the error you mentioned a .NET exception? If so, look into the stacktrace of the exception to find out where the error happens.

Comment: Were you ever able to figure this out? I have the exact same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same error and this fixed it for me. Change the EncodeChunk method in the Lame.cs file to this:

```
public static uint EncodeChunk(uint hbeStream, byte[] buffer, int index, uint nBytes, byte[] pOutput, ref uint pdwOutput) {
    uint res;
    GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(buffer, GCHandleType.Pinned);
    try {
        IntPtr ptr = (IntPtr)(handle.AddrOfPinnedObject() + index);
        res = beEncodeChunk(hbeStream, nBytes / 2/*Samples*/, ptr, pOutput, ref pdwOutput);
    } finally {
        handle.Free();
    }
    return res;
}
```

It was being cast to an Int32 but the address space is too large.